# SplTempFileObject and Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using MySQL database to save some fonts. I need to create image with custom font-family text. I'm using SplTempFileObject to deal with setFont method, but here is what imagick says:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickDrawException' with message 'The given font is not found in the ImageMagick configuration and the file ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]php:/temp) is not accessible'
```

(of course $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is the real value, i just replaced it) :)

Any solution or I have to save font in file system ?

Here is the code:

```
 $image = new \Imagick();
 $draw = new \ImagickDraw();

 $temp = new \SplTempFileObject();
 $temp->fwrite($font->getFile()->getContent());

 $image->newImage(550, 50, "black");
 $draw->setFont($temp);
```

$font is data from DB. I think the problem is because ImagickDraw::setFont() search the font relatively to DOC ROOT.

Comment: what does var_dump(is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'php:/temp')) output?

Comment: Can you add the code that show are you are using `SplTempFileObject`

Comment: @artragis no it's not dir. And it shouldn't be. What i wanted to say is that imagick search the font relatively to document root.

Comment: so you want to access a file by absolute adress?

Comment: @artragis I don't know if that is the problem. With     `$draw->setFont('/'.$temp->getFileName());` same problem.

I want to use SplTempFileObject with setFont, instead of writing file to filesystem.

Comment: instead of getFileName->getRealPath http://php.net/manual/fr/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php

Comment: @artragis SplTempFileObject extends SplFileObject which extends SplFileInfo, which has getRealPath. So getFileName() returns string,that causes call to a member function on non-object, directly $object->getRealPath returns false, because file is in memory.

Comment: @artragis here is what getFileName() returns:

`string(10) "php://temp"`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is caused by the SplTempFileObject that uses in-memory caching up to 2MB per default.
`\SplTempFileObject->getFileName()` will return `php://temp`
`\SplTempFileObject->getFileInfo()` will return an empty object / file pointer
`\SplTempFileObject->getRealPath()` will always return an empty string!

If you want PHP to write a real file in the filesystem, you have to provide in-memory limit `0` as a construct parameter BUT you still won't get a valid `SplFileInfo` nor pathName nor fileName for it other than `php://temp/maxmemory:0`

YES: That's weird and far away from "a simple interface" for creating temp files..

for details, please have a look at http://php.net/manual/spltempfileobject.construct.php

Go back, use the old `tempfile()` or `tempnam()`. My solution:

instead of 

`$file = new \SplTempFileObject();`

I use 

`$file = new \SplFileObject(tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), rand()), 'w+');`

Comment: Yep, that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from an error in your adressing.
When you say `"/".$temp->getFileName()` you don't get the path according to the documentation.
So as you have not got the path, your leading "/" says "from server root". Not cool.

You can use [getRealPath](http://php.net/manual/fr/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, there's a bug with `\SplTempFileObject` where even if you do pass `0` into the constructor, you still have a file that's in memory and therefore doesn't have a filepath/realpath.

I've built a tiny, simple PHP7+ class for this:

```
interface TemporaryFile {
    public function handle(\Closure $closure) : void;
    public function write(string $contents): void;
    public function getContents() : string;
    public function chmod(int $mode): void;
    public function getUri() : string; // aka realpath
    public function close() : void;
}

class IO
{
    /**
     * @return TemporaryFile
     */
    public static function getTemporaryFile() : TemporaryFile {
        return new class implements TemporaryFile {
            private $handle;

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->handle = tmpfile();
            }

            public function handle(\Closure $closure) : void {
                $closure($this->handle);
            }

            public function getContents() : string {
                // according to PHP docs file_get_contents has much better performance
                // http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
                return file_get_contents($this->getUri());
            }

            public function getUri() : string {
                return stream_get_meta_data($this->handle)['uri'];
            }

            public function close() : void {
                if (is_resource($this->handle))
                    fclose($this->handle);
            }

            public function write(string $contents): void
            {
                fwrite($this->handle, $contents);
            }

            public function chmod(int $mode): void
            {
                chmod($this->getUri(), $mode);
            }

            public function __destruct() {
                $this->close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

To use it, just do this:

```
$file = IO::getTemporaryFile();
$file->write('foo');
var_dump($file->getContents()); // string(3) "foo"
```

You can see the aforementioned example in a working state here: https://3v4l.org/LYfan#output

And then you have a temporary file that's gonna self the destruct after the process is finished or the class is dereferenced.